# Different test outcome depend on browser - selenide selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-firefoxdriver, selenide

I have number of tests in the juint test class, By using maven environment with Selenide version 3.5.1.
for these tests, browser wil be only opened for the first test and closed at the last test.

I tried to run them using chrome & firefox browsers:

1. Chrome: all test are run successfully
2. Firefox: there are some tests are failed, and I feel it was randomly failed.

For each test, I need to click on button where a pop-box will appear.

- for chrome: each test the pop-box appeared when the button was clicked
- for firefox: randomly the pop-box didn't appear when the button was clicked.

I don't know what is the problem reason!

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to add a temporisation, to wait the pop-up ?

May be in Firefox, the pop-up is slower and your test is going to fast. Because of this your test is looking for an element that isn't already present.

Try something like this

```
 WebDriverWait waitLog = new WebDriverWait(driver, 2);                   
 waitLog.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("b")));
```

OR

```
 WebDriverWait waitLog = new WebDriverWait(driver, 2);             
 waitLog.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.id("b")));
```

Comment: I tired your solution, but still the tests are failed, the pop window can't wait to enter username and password, it disappeared before filling fields!